# Error in importing variables from one python script to another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a set of more than 10 variables defined in `__main__` of one python script and they are needed to import into another python script to use their values inside different methods. I used `from <pythonfile> import var1, var2 ...., var10` in the calling python script but it is giving me error like below:-

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'envName'
```

Sample structure of my A.py and B.py scripts are like this:-
A.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    var1 = "text1"
    var2 = "text2"
    var3 = "text3"
    B.methodA()
```

B.py

```
from A import var1, var2, var3

def methodA()
    print(var1)
```

This is something I am looking for. Basically I have like more than 10 variables to use in another script (both scripts are in same folder) so need some help to find out the best way to do it. I know the process above I am using could be very stupid and wrong.

Can anyone please help me? I am using python3.6
Also what is the best way to import and use these many variables from one python script into another python script?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are you using `envName`?

Comment: What do you mean by "define in `__main__` of one python script"? Do you have the file `a.py` with `if __name__ == '__main__': A=1` and inside `b.py` you do `from a import A`? this ain't gonna work.

Comment: Is the script you're importing from the in same directory? If not, do you have a `__init__.py` script in the subdirectory where the variables are stored? Even a blank one will suffice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that by defining the variables "in `__main__`" you mean you have something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    var1 = 'foo'
```

then you can't directly import `var1` into another script. `__name__` is only `'__main__'` if the file is being run directly. If you're importing it into another script `__name__` is not `'__main__'` so the variables are never defined. Simply taking `var1 = 'foo'` out of `if __name__ == '__main__'` should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Sam ... Just added the sample structure of my scripts and what I want to achieve so can you please help?

Comment: And did you try removing `if __name__ == '__main__'` or placing the variable definitions outside of it?